# Exporting a certificate to a string

Tags: c#, php

I need to have the PHP equivalent of the following c# code:

```
CLIENT_CERTIFICATE = new X509Certificate2("cert.p12", "passphrase", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var stringOfCertWithPrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
```

Basically I need the Base64 string of the P12 file with the private key included.

Currently I have tried the following code but it only gives me the public key:

```
    $cert = 'cert.p12';
    $passphrase = 'passphrase';
    $certinfo = pathinfo($cert);
    $cert = file_get_contents($cert);
    // for PKCS12 files
    openssl_pkcs12_read($cert, $certs, empty($passphrase) ? '' :$passphrase);

    $pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey']);
    $pubcert = explode("\n", $certs['cert']);
    array_shift($pubcert);
    while (!trim(array_pop($pubcert))) {
    }
    array_walk($pubcert, 'trim');
    $pubcert = implode('', $pubcert);
    unset($certs);
    $this->info($pkeyid);
    $this->info($pubcert);
```

Response:

```
Resource id #378
MIIFAzCCA+.....N+0zuETh2yYpbTBbPHbPbd
```

Any help is much appreciated.